# Is there a way to use an "arbitrary" variant as a parameter?

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

Imagine I have some function which is overloaded for many different types.

```
void func(int value){ ... }
void func(double value){ ... }
void func(bool value){ ... }
```

Is there a way I can define it for a std::variant of an **arbitrary** combination of the overloaded types? e.g.

```
template<class... Ts> struct overload : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overload(Ts...) -> overload<Ts...>;

void func(std::variant<> variant)
{
  std::visit(overload{[](auto& value) { func(value); }}, variant);
}
```

Such that I wouldn't have to write a separate overload for each possible template, i.e. in the following example

```
std::variant<int, double> v1;
std::variant<double, bool> v2;
std::variant<int, double, bool> v3;

func(v1);
func(v2);
func(v3);
```

All three calls would use the single "arbitrary variant" overload of func().

Note that there could be many more types involved than just the three primitive types I listed.

Edit: Added additional clarity.

Comment: Have you tried `template<class... Ts> void func(std::variant<Ts...> variant)`?

Comment: Obviously yes.  Type `std::variant<int,double,bool>`.  But I suspect your actual question isn't that.  Please clarify.

Comment: FWIW, if you already have a set of overloads, you can skip the `overload` struct and its deduction guideline entirely by using [`BOOST_HOF_LIFT`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/lift.html) this way: `auto overloeaded_func = BOOST_HOF_LIFT(func);`. Also, if you really need the `overload` function, you can avoid writing it yourself and rely on [`boost::hana::overload`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-functional.html#ga83e71bae315e299f9f5f9de77b012139).

Answer (score 2):

With variadic template, you might do:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void func(const std::variant<Ts...>& variant)
{
    std::visit([](auto& value) { func(value); }, variant);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cc86011dc15b525)